# Retaining file permissions with SVN

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I am sharing a folder in a Linux machine with a Windows7 machine using samba server. From the windows machine, I get [export or check-out] some code files from my SVN repository [using tortoise SVN] to this shared folder. Now I could see that my linux file permissions are changed.

Is it possible to preserve the file permissions in the above case? Can anyone offer some help?

PS: Please let me know know if my problem description is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion does not manage file permissions.

Do not share a working copy between two users, two OSes, or two different SVN client versions. It's heavily discouraged in part because of what you've discovered here.